# WebView2 initialization failed with exception

Tags: pywebview

I get an error while running pywebview application.

```
[pywebview] Using WinForms / Chromium
[1] DEBUG:pywebview:Using WinForms / Chromium
[1] [pywebview] WebView2 initialization failed with exception:
[1]  The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
[1]    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
[1]    at Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment.<CreateCoreWebView2ControllerAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
[1] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[1]    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
[1]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[1]    at Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2.<InitCoreWebView2Async>d__25.MoveNext()
[1] ERROR:pywebview:WebView2 initialization failed with exception:
[1]  The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
[1]    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
[1]    at Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment.<CreateCoreWebView2ControllerAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
[1] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[1]    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
[1]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[1]    at Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2.<InitCoreWebView2Async>d__25.MoveNext()
```

Any suggestion to solve this issue is welcome.

- Pywebview 4.2.2
- Windows 11 pro
- Microsoft Edge 115.0.1901.183 (Official build) (64-bit)

Thanks